# Put question guidelines in sidebar for certain users

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rules, sidebar

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) shows up only when a question is being drafted, after the user clicks "Ask Question."

- New users may look to find questions rules before asking, and be
  unable to find any links. By the time they click "Ask Question" and
  start writing, they may already be committed to asking. (Even though
  this is not ideal behavior.)
- New users may not think that a question under "Helpful links" with
  "information about how to ask a good question here" are actually more
  like rules for which questions they are allowed to ask. The current
  phrasing makes it seem like the link may contain information such as
  how to ask a clear question, avoid grammar mistakes, etc., and may
  not know it contains topics that are or aren't within-scope for the
  site.
- The link in the sidebar (perhaps displayed somewhere around "Hot
  Network Questions") should probably go away automatically for
  experienced users above a certain number of questions or reputation.
- Perhaps the link text should read something like "Question Guidelines" or "Guidelines and rules for questions."

I am wondering if the community thinks this is a good idea, a bad idea, or an idea which may be useful but only with added stipulations or modifications.

(Though, Stack Overflow is better than some other Stack Exchange sites, which sometimes have question rules spread out over multiple pages, requiring multiple clicks to arrive at any one.)

Here is an example of what it could look like (though there are many text / placement options):

[image]

(It might look better as a button to visually separate it from the other text.)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding things to the side bar means taking things away, given they aren't allowed (or refuse to) change the location of the ad blocks.

Comment: @KevinB Good point. What do you think about adding it right below the ad block? This would shift the "Hot Network Questions" section down slightly.

Comment: The placement of where you suggest the guidance to be doesn't give enough emphasis to it, people generally ignore things in the right sidebar and one line over there is not noticeable enough. The Ask Wizard tries to present [some guidance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJl9q.png) to the user but I feel that the wording pretty much glosses over the fact that those links might be important to read.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I agree that there is not enough emphasis where it is now. I still think there is some value for it somewhere in the side bar, for new-ish users who actively want to find the guidelines, and may be familiar with the "rules-in-sidebar" convention of other sites (e.g., Reddit) or just assume that they can find useful information there.

Comment: _"should probably go away automatically for experienced users above a certain number of questions or reputation."_ No, I think something like this should remain in place, even for high rep users. For two reasons: 1) quick access if they want to look it up themselves, and 2) uniformity of interface so high reputation users can tell low reputation users where they can find something; and maybe a bonus reason: some high rep users might be good at answering questions, but not so good at asking them.

Comment: [yes, it's a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394872/997587). I personally don't think this proposed solution is the most intuitive. Not everyone who visits SO wants to write a question post. I think people should be throw into guidance when they want to as a question, and be guided by the UI/UX to read it before being given a UI to draft a question post. I've floated [a rather dramatic idea about it in chat before](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56679929#56679929).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, that's a good point (especially if it's a small link)

Comment: It's fun times we live in. You can't do message boxes, people are conditioned to ignore message boxes due to the state of the web today with all the cookie nags, requests to send notifications, ads, etc. etc. You can't do the sidebar, it contains so much noise that for most people it's just invisible. What can you do to get through to people nowadays eh?

Comment: @Gimby The sidebar would be invisible to most, yes, but it would help those specifically looking for the rules